# Is there a way to link to a new page with react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to react. I am using react to list stores, when the user clicks on the store it will show just the menu and nothing else. The problem that I am facing is that everytime i click on a store the menu is shown right below the list of stores. I want it to be rendered as a new page with nothing but the menu. Is there a way i can do that with react router? Below is my code. Any help would be really appreciated

```
   <Router>
       <div> {stores.map((store) => (

           <div><Link to="/storemenu"> {store} </Link> <br/></div>


       ))} <button onClick={()=>addStore()}>Add Store</button>

       </div>


       <Switch>

       </Switch>
           <Route exact path="/storemenu">
               <StoreMenu/>
           </Route>

       </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

By rendering whatever outside of all `Route`s you automatically make it appear site-wide (on all routes).

If you don't want list of stores to appear on all pages - just render it inside some other `Route`.

If, on the other hand, you want list of stores to appear on some pages but not on some others (like `/storemenu`), render list of stores inside a `Route` & pass to this route an array of paths where list of stores should appear as `path`.

Then write another `Switch` inside this `Route` & handle other routing logic as needed.

Here is a minimalistic example that works:

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  const store = ["Berlin", "Moscow"];

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <nav> { /* This nav is visible on all pages */ }
          <Link to="/some">
            /some
          </Link>
          <Link to="/pages">
            /pages
          </Link>
          <Link to="/storemenu">
            /storemenu
          </Link>
        </nav>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={["/", "/some", "/pages"]}>
            { /* Stores are visible only on "/", "/some" & "/pages" */ }
            {store.map((store) => {
              return store;
            })}
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/some">
                A page with list
              </Route>
              <Route path="/pages">
                Another page with list
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/storemenu">
            Here is Store Menu with no stores list!
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```